# Никак не могу разобраться с циклом while и его выводом

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, while

Нужно, чтобы в output выводились все числа, которые попадают в условие 10 < x <= 100. Очень важно, чтобы эти числа выводились не как только из ввел(как у меня), а уже после завершения цикла

```
while True:
    num = int(input())
    if num < 10:
        continue
    elif num > 100:
        break
    if num >= 10:
        print(num)
```

Comment: складывайте в список

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и написал splash58, просто складываем всё в список и выводим.

```
l = [] # пустой список для заполнения данными
while True:
    num = int(input())
    if num < 10:
        continue
    elif num > 100:
        print(l) # когда выходим из цикла, выводим накопленные числа
        break
    else:
        l += [num] # добавляем в список все подходящие числа
```

Comment: последний if не нужен - раз мы туда попали, num больше 10. и ``l.append(num)`

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение) очень лаконично и прям так, как хотелось)